# Unable to click the 'button' in selenium webdriver (using Java)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This is the code where I want to locate the href button :

```
<a class="btn grey-edit" data-original-title="Login" data-placement="top" 
data-toggle="tooltip" href="/users/userlogin/3">
<i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

I am using the following xpath but it is not working :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/div/button")).click();
```

[this the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNaKC.jpg)

Comment: Try please to be more specific. How did you setup Selenium? What's your HTML code that you're trying to traverse?

Comment: HTML code does not contain a button that you mention in the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have provided, the **`href`** attribute is within an **`<a>`** tag. So we will construct a unique logical **`xpath`** to locate the **`WebElement`** and invoke **`click()`** method as follows :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn grey-edit' and @data-original-title='Login']")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn grey-edit']/i[@class='fa fa-sign-in']")).click();
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Can you paste the entire error stack trace?

Comment: Actually no error showing. I am sharing the test case you can understand then. 1. Opening the website url  2. Login  3. going to user page 4. Now want to open the X user account through that button (mention in question). And here I am unable to do that. the whole script running well  user page opening as usual but can't click the X user button

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement btnElem= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn grey-edit' and @href='/users/userlogin/3']"));
btnElem.click();
```

You can also use the JavaScriptExecutor for the same

```
WebElement btnElem= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn grey-edit' and @href='/users/userlogin/3']"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", btnElem);
```

Comment: what is the issue

Comment: I am unable to click the login button(mention in question). Your suggested code didn't work. Is there any other option instead of xpath ?

Comment: I dont see the another way as there is NO ID name to locate your element

Comment: Actually no error showing. I am sharing the test case you can understand then. 1. Opening the website url 2. Login 3. going to user page 4. Now want to open the X user account through that button (mention in question). And here I am unable to do that. the whole script running well user page opening as usual but can't click the X user button   **This is the Case**

Comment: Please check whether it is in iframe??

Comment: Same is working fine in my side, Please share the URL

Comment: So do u find anything helpful?